# Proper Way To Use .Net DateTime in Parameterized SQL String

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oracle, datetime

There are several questions about using .Net DateTime in Sql statements but none of them solved my problem.

I'm using the following code to query an Oracle database :

```
private DataTable QueryByIdAndDate(string id, DateTime fdate, DateTime tdate) {
    string query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = :id AND DATE_TIME BETWEEN :from AND :to"
    DbCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = query;

    DbParameter fromDate = CreateDateParameter(cmd, fdate);
    fromDate.ParameterName = "from";
    DbParameter toDate = CreateDateParameter(cmd, tdate);
    toDate.ParameterName = "to"; 
    DbParameter idParam = CreateStringParameter(cmd, id);
    idParam.ParameterName = "id";

    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new DbParameter[] { fromDate, toDate, idParam });
    return db.ExecuteQuery(cmd);
}

private DbParameter CreateDateParameter(DbCommand cmd, DateTime date) {
    DbParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
    param.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    param.Value = date;
    return param;
}
```

But it does not work properly. When trying the code out like so:

```
DataTable result = QueryByIdAndDate("12345", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
```

It gives the following error: 
    ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

I'm assuming it has to do with the way the DateTime is formatted but I don't know the proper way to fix this in a reliable way.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be running it for the 30th of a month with only 30 days would you?

Comment: Nope. It failed with the example I showed using DateTime.Now and DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

Comment: Does your driver definitely support named parameters? If it's trying to use them by position, it'll end up using the "id" value as the "to" part, which could be broken. Which driver are you using?

Comment: @JonSkeet Wow you guessed it. I'm using Oracle.DataAccess and it must be using them by position because I changed the order of the parameters as I put them into the array and now it is working. What an annoying result after an hour of messing with it. Put that as an answer and you win, thank you!

Comment: @user12345613: Good to see psychic debugging working every so often :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(As per comments...)

It looks like in this case, the order of the parameters matters... despite the fact that you've given them names. I wouldn't have expected this, and it's the sign of a somewhat broken driver, but changing your code to:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new DbParameter[] { idParam, fromDate, toDate });
```

should fix it. (This isn't necessarily the way you should be constructing your parameters, by the way, but that's somewhat immaterial here.)

Do *not* start specifying the date/time values as strings. It's a *really bad idea* to introduce any more string conversions than you need.

Comment: Yes I didn't even think about the order of that array (which was foolish) since they are named parameters. Also, I'm open for any comments or suggestions on properly constructing the parameters.

Comment: In my experience there are lots of things broken in oracle .net drivers, including parameter order or the need to change SQL statements in order to get rid of NULL reference exceptions.

Comment: @user12345613: I can't say it's an area I have much experience with, but if you use the strongly-typed command parameter collection, you're likely to get options such as `AddWithValue` which make life easier.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'll have to check that out. As for now, I'm glad this is working.

Comment: The OracleCommand object in ODP.Net has a property called `BindByName`, which when set to true eliminates this problem. It is set to false by default because previous versions of the driver(s) used to bind by position.

Comment: After 2 hours on trying formatting a correct datetime i found this answer!! worked like a charm!

Comment: I assumed ODP.NET for entity framework 6 would utilize `BindByName`, but this was not the case when executing a raw sql query via `context.SqlQuery(sql, new OracleParameter[]{})`.  I'm still unable to find `BindByName` when utilizing `context.SqlQuery`, but this answer worked in the mean time.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the `DateTime` value to a formatted date string:

```
private DbParameter CreateDateParameter(DbCommand cmd, DateTime date) 
{
     DbParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
     param.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
     param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
     param.Value = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
     return param;
}
```

Even though you are sending a string value, the `DbType` is still set to `DateTime`, so the value should get converted properly.

Comment: Note that even if this were actually the problem, you'd probably want to use the invariant culture, and you'd definitely want to change "hh" to "HH". I would strongly advise *against* performing such conversions yourself though.

Comment: Nothing gets by @JonSkeet. Agreed, I jumped straight to the formatting issue and never considered the parameter order. Updated per your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle expects dates formatted as 'DD-Mon-YYYY', so you need to basically format your date value that way and assign it to the parameter value.

Edit: I've noticed that recent versions of ODP seem to handle date time parameters better. For example, this works just fine when there is a constraint on a WHERE clause over a date/time column:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2012, 5, 21);
cmd.Parameters.Add("some_date_param", dt);
```

Running a query this way with the latest version of ODP works fine. But I have a lot of code where date/time values need to be passed as formatted strings in order for Oracle to accept them.

Answer (score 2):

For those that might miss it, see the comment by **@kprobst** under [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10305391/98422) by **@JonSkeet**:

It doesn't matter how well you format the parameter values etc. if you're trying to use name binding without setting the `BindByName` property on the `Command`.

(The whole Oracle provider API is a pile of junk IMHO).